# Jobs are not returning valid WS.HttpResponse data with Play 1.4.0

Tags: java, playframework

I have jobs that return a WS.HttpResponse result like:

```
public class GetMessage extends Job<HttpResponse> {

    ...

    public HttpResponse doJobWithResult() {
        HttpResponse resp = WS.url(url).get();
        return resp;
    }
}
```

This is how I get the result from the job:

```
HttpResponse response = await(new GetMessage(params).now());
```

When I attempt to call getString() or getStream() using the "response" object I'm not getting any data.

If I call getString() in the job on "resp" then it has the data as expected.

It's strange because this worked with Play 1.2.4 - Play 1.2.7.2.

After the await I do have a non null "response" object and I can call getStatus() on it and it returns a 200, but maybe that's the default when WS.HttpResponse is initialized.  I'm thinking that maybe I'm getting a new WS.HttpResponse() rather than the one returned from the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  I was calling getString() to construct an error message that I would log if I got an error response.  This was clearing the stream.  I'm not sure why it worked the way it was in play <= 1.2.7.2.

Perhaps the InputStream should be closed and throw when calling getStream after getString or getStream have been called?